# Perform a action when checkbox is clicked Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I basically want to know when the user has clicked the checkbox. If checkbox is clicked then I want the div to output a msg and once checkbox is not checked then output another msg but user has to check first. The checkbox gets created dynamically. But somehow I dont know what the value is.

There are 2 problems:

- When checkbox is clicked, the check mark does not stay
- If checkbox is clicked, a value does not output on the div

Here is a example:
    http://jsfiddle.net/8GjdS/103/

Code:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click #check': 'checkboxHandler'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'checkboxHandler');
    },

    checkboxHandler: function(e) {
        var filter = $('#check').is(':checked');
        console.log(filter);
         $('#out').append(filter);
        return false;
    },

});
var v = new myView({el: '#view-goes-here'});
v.render();


 $('#view-goes-here').append('<div class=divs" align="right"><input id="check" type="checkbox" value=""><font size="4">check</font></input></div>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.

First: When you `return false` from an event handler (or trigger `event.preventDefault()` you stop the event from bubbling up. That means, you handle the event yourself and it will never trigger the usual action -- in this case, it means the checkbox will never change. You should `return true` instead, in your checkbox handler.

Second: The value is not appended to your `out` div because you call the append function with a boolean as the argument. The easiest way in this case is probably to "cast" it to a string like so:

```
$('#out').append('' + filter);
```

Third: While it's a workable approach to listen for the `click` event, it could be argued that it's more correct to listen for the `change` event instead. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change):

> The change event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the user.

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jzvzgdp4/

Comment: I think the docs are quite good. But none of this is specific to Backbone; it's just javascript and the DOM.